# Automatically load settings.json on starting Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Rather than starting Meteor with the flag `--settings settings.json`

```
mrt --settings settings.json
```

Is it possible to define `Meteor.Settings` automatically on startup by just running

```
mrt
```

Comment: what about nowadays?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nowadays the command should be `meteor` (no more `mrt`):

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

---

To automatically load settings file, I like the method suggested on "[The Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/#tmc-automating-settingsjson)" that exploits `npm`:

Creating a file `package.json` in the project root:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings.json"
  }
}
```

We can start meteor with:

```
npm start
```

---

**DEV/PROD**

Also it is possible to have two or more scripts for two or more settings:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "meteor:dev": "meteor --settings settings-dev.json",
    "meteor:prod": "meteor --settings settings-prod.json"
  }
}
```

Then:

```
npm run meteor:dev
```

or

```
npm run meteor:prod
```

(note that here we have to add the `run` command, not required with the "special" script `start`)

Comment: Thanks for the update, the `npm start` method is interesting! Is it possible to also export the variables `MONGO_URL` and `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` using this method?

Comment: Think it can be done using `env set MONGO_URL` in the `meteor:dev` and `meteor:prod` values?

Comment: @Nyxynyx yes, maybe with something like `env MONGO_URL="<some value>" MONGO_OPLOG_URL="<another value>" meteor --settings settings.json`

Comment: Warning! This method is for making Node consume 100% of your CPU for some reason. Please use the alias method from below answer if that happens to you (just replace `mrt` with `meteor`).

Answer (score 7):

For dev, use an [alias](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/jan.plaza/computing/help/newcommands.html)

```
alias mrt='mrt --settings settings.json'
```

or

```
alias mrts='mrt --settings settings.json'
```

remove it with `unalias mrts`

When you want it to be permanent, put it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

Alternatively, meteor accepts an environment variable (useful for production)

```
METEOR_SETTINGS = `cat path/to/settings.json`
export METEOR_SETTINGS
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to fiddle with aliases, you could create a bash script in the root directory of a specific project, like so:

**dev.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
meteor --settings ./config/development/settings.json
```

And just run it from the meteor project directory with:

```
./dev.sh
```

If you get `-bash: ./dev.sh: Permission denied` just do:

```
chmod +x ./dev.sh
```

If you use other services you could start them before meteor like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service elasticsearch start
meteor --settings ./config/development/settings.json
```

Comment: Yeah, I've actually swapped over to launching meteor this way. For the exact reason of starting services / setting environments